# Clone certain branch of SVN repository from Google Code

Tags: svn, version-control, box2d

The question title is self-explanatory.
I need a way to clone(I'm a git user, so I've gotten used to that terminology) the branch box2d_2.0 from the svn repo - https://code.google.com/p/pybox2d/source/checkout

How do I do that? Googling didn't give me anything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to construct the path in the URL correctly, following the example for `trunk`, like this:

```
svn checkout http://pybox2d.googlecode.com/svn/branches/box2d_2.0 pybox2d-read-only
```